# Average b/w two dates stored as int

Tags: php

i want to show average diff of 2 dates colums as in int data type.
i know how to show if thats date column but not now how with int data type.

i tried this but nothing shows:

```
mysql_query("select AVG(update - date) AS avg_time from qchat_sessions");
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

i used this query now and it shows `153.000`

```
$sss=mysql_query("select AVG(`update` - `date`) AS avg_time from qchat_sessions");
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sss);

echo $rows[0];
```

and dates are stored in int data type. now how can i show in time ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is most likely that `update` and `date` are clashing with the similarly named MySQL keywords.

Try quoting them:

```
SELECT AVG(`update` - `date`) AS avg_time FROM qchat_sessions
```

If that doesn't help, check the output of `mysql_error()` for hints.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query below:

```
    SELECT AVG(
           DATEDIFF(MIN(qchat_sessions.update), posts.date)
          ) 
FROM qchat_sessions
```